# Embedding hi or low res assets? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Im embeding assets into my as3 like:

```
[Embed(source = "assets/images/"+assetSizeString+"/ui/left_thumb.png")]
private static const leftThumb:Class;
```

and I want assetSizeString to denote whether hi res or lo res assets are imported but I get the error 'Invalid Metadata'

Does anyone have any advice how to select hi or low assets using embed? Or fix this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use conditional compilation.

```
[Embed(source=config::LEFT_THUMB)]
private static const leftThumb:Class;
```

And as a parameter to `mxmlc`:

```
mxmlc MyApplication.as \
  -define=config::LEFT_THUMB,"'assets/images/100px/ui/left_thumb.png'"
```

Note: the value is surrounded by single quotes, then double quotes.

Now I imagine you have lots of assets like this in your application. Depending on how you're compiling it (`mxmlc` command line or `ant` script), I would use either a shell variable to hold the value "100px", which is then interpolated into each asset file name, or a variable within the `ant` script.

If you're using Flash Builder then I'm afraid you might be out of luck, but I'm not an expert on that tool so maybe there's a way.